# Button in bootstrap not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to use bootstrap(4) to creat a website. I got stuck at creating menu with dropdown lists. I cannot make it work, I even tried copying exact code of the docs for bootstrap and it still doesnt work. I have checked and rechecked paths for bootstrap css and js and I really dont know how to make it work.

While at it, can I use bootstrap to create dropdown lists inside dropside lists? It is for Menu purposes.

bootstrap docs, w3schools and other websites. even copying exact code makes no difference, the button doesnt work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">

<title>Animal World</title>

<style>

</style>
```

```
<img src="animalworld.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Animal">

 <div class="dropdown fixed-top bg-faded ">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="DropDownAnimals" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Animals
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="DropDownAnimals">
        <button class="dropdown-item" >Dogs</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Horses</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Birds</button>
    </div>
</div> 

<!--<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-collapse-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Animal World</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MainMenu" aria-controls="MainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="MainMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Animals</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stuff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>-->






<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
</script>
```

In the above code there are two different parts of code both for similar button. First doesnt work at all. second does, but in a way that just makes button move to right and the 3 other buttons appear on left. unable to change it at all. I would expect the dropdown come directly underneath the button as per docs.

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate Bootstrap version.

Comment: Do _any_ Bootstrap features work? Do you see any 404 errors in the browser console?

Comment: bootstrap 4, and it has been solved, thank you so much @isherwood

Comment: Please _tag your question_ with the appropriate Bootstrap version. It doesn't matter that it's been solved. It's now part of the community resource collection and should be tagged properly so that _other people_ can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're importing your scripts in the wrong order. 
Try putting the jquery script tag first, then the popper script, then you Bootstrap scripts.

And to answer your subsidiary question, it is absolutely possible to put a dropdown into a dropdown.

Comment: I cannot believe this was the right solution, so simple! Care to share how did you know that? also why is this the case? many thanks!

Comment: See this as a kind of dependency. Bootstrap needs Jquery to run. And it basically is in TWBS documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) note the friendly comment above the scripts.

Comment: completely missed this despite reading that page... well thank you for sharing your knowledge, I shall be less slopy in the future! :)

Comment: _Any_ jQuery library or plugin must be loaded after jQuery. It's a simple dependency chain.